# Applying jQuery event functions to new Knockout.js array elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js, ko.observablearray

I have a Knockout.js viewmodel with a list of `products`, which are populated by an ASP.NET Web API call:

```
// Define viewmodel
var myViewModel = {
    products = ko.observableArray([]);
};

// Apply knockout bindings
ko.applyBindings(vm);

// Function that obtains product data
function listProducts(viewmodel) {
    var productsQuery = "api/products/get";

    // Send an AJAX request
    $.getJSON(productsQuery).done(viewmodel.products);
}
```

When I call `listProducts`, each element is added successfully to the ff. HTML `<ul>`:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: products">
    <li class="item">
        <data-bind="text: productName">
    </li>
</ul>
```

However, when each item is added, the jQuery function that applies to my `.item` elements:

```
$(".item").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
});
```

does not get applied to these newly added elements.

**Question: How do I add elements to the Knockout.js observableArray that will also inherit their corresponding jQuery methods?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to go back to the knockout docs and read, read, read! Forget doing this with jquery, it's just not the ko way. Knockout frees you from this kind of coding style, you just need to **grok** it.

hint:

use the click binding and the css binding

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html

As an aside you can also do this:

```
 $.getJSON(productsQuery).done(viewmodel.products);
```

Comment: Thank you for the code shortening tip, I'll apply that to the question's code to shorten it. I will look into your hint and give it a try in my code.